# What arguments can I pass to dbConnect?

Tags: r, database-connection

To connect to a SQLite database, it is reasonably straightforward: you pass a driver and a path to the SQLite file.

For other [`DBI`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/DBI)-compatible database backends (PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.), what you can pass to [`dbConnect`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/DBI/docs/dbConnect) isn't obvious, nor well documented.

How do I find out what I can pass to `dbConnect` to form the connection?

Answer (score 16):

The arguments available depend upon the backend, which is why `dbConnect` only shows driver and `...` arguments.

Before we proceed, load the packages required for the database connection (`RSQLite`, `RPostgreSQL`, `RMySQL` or whatever).

---

**To find the name of the driver**

This should be the same as the name of the database backend.  Currently supported values include
`"SQLite"`, `"PostgreSQL"`, `"MySQL"`, `"Oracle"`, `"JDBC"`.

The string must always be the name of a function in the DB package, so if in doubt search through the package (use, for example, `ls("package:RSQLite")`) and guess at names that look plausible.

---

**To find the ... args**

You can see the methods available for connection using [`showMethods`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/methods/topics/showMethods).

```
showMethods("dbConnect")
## Function: dbConnect (package DBI)
## drv="character"
## drv="PostgreSQLConnection"
## drv="PostgreSQLDriver"
## drv="SQLiteConnection"
## drv="SQLiteDriver"
```

Get the method for the appropriate backend, with `Driver` in the name.

```
getMethod(dbConnect, "PostgreSQLDriver")
# The 'Method Definition' section of the output
## function (drv, ...) 
## postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...)
```

The available arguments are are those of the function that is called inside the previous method definition.

[`?postgresqlNewConnection`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RPostgreSQL/topics/postgresqlSupport)

```
args(postgresqlNewConnection)
## function (drv, user = "", password = "", host = "", dbname = "", 
##     port = "", tty = "", options = "", forceISOdate = TRUE)
```

SQLite and MySQL call locally defined functions, which are a bit of a pain to access programmatically.

[`?SQLite`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RSQLite/topics/SQLite)

```
args(body(getMethod("dbConnect", "SQLiteDriver"))[[2]][[3]])
## function (drv, dbname = "", ..., loadable.extensions = TRUE, 
## cache_size = NULL, synchronous = "off", flags = SQLITE_RWC, 
## vfs = NULL) 
## function (...)
```

[`?MySQL`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RMySQL/topics/MySQLDriver-class)

```
args(body(getMethod("dbConnect", "MySQLDriver"))[[2]][[3]])
## function (drv, dbname = NULL, username = NULL, password = NULL, 
## host = NULL, unix.socket = NULL, port = 0, client.flag = 0, 
## groups = "rs-dbi", default.file = NULL, ...
```

[?`OraSupport`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ROracle/versions/0.5-12/topics/oraSupport)

```
# Oracle
args(.oci.Connect)
## function(drv, username = "", password = "", dbname = "", prefetch = FALSE, 
##     bulk_read = 1000L, stmt_cache = 0L, external_credentials = FALSE, 
##     sysdba = FALSE)
```

`RJDBC` works slightly differently. Rather than calling another subfunction, its `dbConnect` method accepts additional named args.

```
formalArgs(getMethod(dbConnect, "JDBCDriver"))
## [1] "drv"      "url"      "user"     "password" "..."
```

Comment: Unfortunately links to r-inside.org seem to be dead. Also, I cannot find `sqliteNewConnection` nor `mysqlNewConnection` (no longer exported since v0.10 https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL/blob/7c3ba1dc8bd59ba972350401f4c421b12da03253/NEWS.md#version-010)