# Does anyone know how to connect localhost in R?

Tags: java, sql, r, localhost, rjdbc

```
drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver","C:/sqljdbc_3.0/enu/sqljdbc4.jar")

conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://.", "Login", "password")
```

But i want to connect my computers local host windows aunthentication so i tried this:

```
conn2 <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:windowsauthentication://.", "admin", "123456")
```

What is the mistake in here? How can i connect my localhost?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What arguments can I pass to dbConnect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119142/what-arguments-can-i-pass-to-dbconnect)

Answer (score 0):

Try using ODBC:
1. Create ODBC connection to localhost
2. Connect R to created ODBC, refer https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf

Hope this helps.